# Docker vs Cluster with Node.js

Tags: node.js

I was learning Node.js and came across some of the ways to scale an app using Node. So, basically there are two ways: Clusterization and Worker threads. So, I would kindly like to ask a question on scalability of Node.js. So, as far as I understood, clusterization helps to create several instances of node.js app which in turn helps to serve more requests. But the question is Can't we achieve the same with docker?, that is, wrap one instance of Node.js app and create clones out of it and then use load balancer in front of them. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do both, but it really depends on how you want to architect your application. If each instance is relatively independent then you can just spin up N containers, each with a Node process. If they're interdependent you may want to use a single container with a forked process manager in it.

Keep in mind that a lot of the clusterization tools are built to solve the same problems that Docker itself does so there will be overlap in functionality here.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I just want independent clones being ready to serve loads of requests )). So, if you were in my position, would you use docker or clusterization? Sorry just a side question : ), question concerning building large backend with Node.js. With the availability of worker threads, can we really create large backend system using Node.js instead of using Java(Spring) or Asp.net? I just wanted to focus on Node.js entirely and try to do something with it))

Comment: In my experience the clusterization never worked that well. I've always used a combination of Nginx and [Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com) to do the process management. Lately I've pivoted to using Docker + Kubernetes to achieve the same thing, one Node process per container.

Comment: Since the cost of a container is largely proportional to the process in it, having N containers with 1 process each and 1 container with N processes is effectively the same in terms of resource usage. The difference is multiple containers can be easier to manage with Kubernetes, it's just a number you can change on the fly, and it makes rolling deployments possible. Docker (and Docker Swarm) doesn't have the same automation features, but if your application is successful you'll probably end up migrating to something like Kubernetes anyway, so pays to be prepared.

Comment: ok, then I m gonna focus on docker + kubernetes and abstain from clusters). Sorry, I think you missed my last question : ) that was about Node.js in huge enterprise apps. Can we use it instead of, say, Java(Spring). Because Node.js basically is used as BFF and not used as REAL backend. Can we just use it as real backend since we have worker threads now helping to unload event loop. Thnk you ))

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using Node or Java in a back-end capacity, both are capable of doing the job. The only obstacles I see to using them is either cultural resistance, or a lack of team knowledge. Don't forget Node has WebWorkers if you need to do some heavy computation that would otherwise block the event loop and wreck the async model. These aren't exactly the same as threads, but they solve the same problem.

Comment: If you want to know more about using Node in "enterprise" situations you may want to look at archived Node conf talks about such things.